# Error with custom session handler

Tags: php, session, couchbase

With the code below, adding the `call_user_func_array` for `session_set_save_handler` causes every single page to have the following non-descriptive error after all content. (past the `</html>` tag on my pages). Its as if some `shutdown` / `destruct` method is causing it.

```
Fatal error: Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas what would be causing this?

#### code in question

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/", $pitchcare_settings['cookiehost'], False, False);
$Couchbase = new Couchbase($server_settings['couchbase']['host'], $server_settings['couchbase']['usename'], $server_settings['couchbase']['password'], $server_settings['couchbase']['bucket'], $server_settings['couchbase']['persistent']);

call_user_func_array('session_set_save_handler', array(
    function($savePath, $name) use ($Couchbase)  { // open
        return true;
    },
    function() use ($Couchbase) { // close
        return true;
    },
    function($key) use ($Couchbase)  { // read
        try {
            return json_decode($Couchbase->get($key), true);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    function($key, $data) use ($Couchbase) { // write
        $Couchbase->delete($key);
        return $Couchbase->add($key, json_encode($value), 10);
    },
    function($key = null) use ($Couchbase)  { // destroy
        return $Couchbase->delete($key);
    },
    function($maxlifetime) use ($Couchbase)  { // gc
        return true;
    },
));
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

session_start();
```